# Why does the auth component access the `users` table, despite me not using a model named `Users`?

Tags: php, database, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm using cakephp 4 and when I'm trying to login a User it says me there was no table called Users. But I used "Users" nowhere in my code, only "User" without the "s".

[image: CakePHP error screen]

I don't find the bug and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what can easily happen when you're fighting the naming conventions, as the CakePHP framework follows a convention over configuration approach.

The conventions for database table names (and table classes for that matter) is to use plurals, so `users` instead of `user`, hence wherever CakePHP provides model/table names as defaults, it will use plural names accordingly.

By default the auth component's authenticators (which is deprecated btw, you should look into using the [**authentication plugin**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html) instead) are configured to use the `Users` model/table alias, plural. The related option is `userModel`, which you would need to change accordingly if you wanted to use a different model. There's other options that use plurals too, like the ones that define URL arrays, they use `Users` to target `UsersController` (controller names are by convention plural too).

The model layer also has entities, and the convention for entities is to use singular names, so `User`. This is another reason not to use singular names for tables, even if you can by configuring things, it can easily cause confusion with entity class names.

I would very strongly suggest that you follow the conventions, and that you use use the bake console to create your models, controllers, etc., especially if you're a beginner. Once you're familiar with the ins and outs of CakePHP you can start with bending it to your will, and deviate from the conventions in case necessary.

See also

- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/intro/conventions.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Bake Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/index.html)**

Comment: Oh... okay, I changed the `userModel` option and it works. But I going to change my table name to respect cakePhP conventions.

Thanks very much for your help !